# GIT cross checkout and dependency check for jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, git-bash

I have following git project structure:

```
MAIN_PRJ
  SUB_MODULE1
  SUB_MODULE2
     SUB_MODULE2_1
  SUB_MODULE3
     SUB_MODULE3_1
         SUBMODULE_3_1_1
```

As part of my jenkins job trigger, the trigger message that passed contains fetch commands for curtain sub-modules, passed as a string. For example:

```
git fetch https://git.server/SUB_MODULE1 hash_commit;git fetch https://git.server/SUB_MODULE2_1 hash_commit;git fetch https://git.server/SUB_MODULE3_1_1 hash_commit
```

We use those for cross dependency checks.
I am looking for a way to make all those "fetches" recursively.

One of the direction -

1. running `git submodule foreach --recursive 'git remote -v'`command
2. get the remote from it
3. compare remote path to fetch path
4. if true execute the fetch command

`git remote -v`  Command returns the origin for fetch and push, Is there a way to get only one of them? Is there a way to store this remote value as a parameter ? The path during the recursive run stored as pwd parameter.

In my vision it will look like that:

```
foreach fetch_remote in fetchlist:
    git submodule foreach --recursive 'git remote -v;if [$origin==$fetch_remote] then fetch_command fi'
```

Any other Ideas?

Update:
So far I managed to combine following command that partly works:

```
foreach fetch_remote in fetchlist:
   git submodule foreach --recursive 'sub_remote=$(git remote get-url origin);if[$sub_remote==$fetch_remote];then $fetch_command; fi'
```

But I am getting an error, for explanation let assume that  fetch_remote="http://git_remote/SUB_MODULE2_1"

```
/usr/lib/git-core/git-submodule: 1: eval: [http://git_remote/SUB_MODULE2_1==http://git_remote/SUB_MODULE2_1]: not found
```

Comment: Try with spaces and single `=`: `if [ $origin = $fetch_remote ]; then`

Comment: Tried this:
' git submodule foreach --recursive 'sub_remote=$(git remote get-url origin);if [ $sub_remote=$fetch_remote ];then $fetch_command; fi' '
But now getting always YES printing - avoiding if condition

Answer (score 0):

Found solution that work for me:

```
foreach fetch_remote in fetchlist:
    git submodule foreach --recursive 'if [ "$(git remote get-url origin)"  = "$fetch_remote" ]; then fetch_command; fi'
```